# Pulling a remote repository

Tags: git, git-pull

I'm a fairly new Git user who's only familiar with basic commands. I've cloned a Git repository to a local branch, then used:

```
git add file.txt
git commit -m 'my message'
git push
```

So far, this is working fine to commit. Now, I've been asked to pull my changes into the remote repository. Since this is the first time I've ever done this, I want to do so 'safely,' without making any inadvertent changes to the remote repo. I'd also like to review the commits before pulling them so I'm sure I'm pulling in the right ones.

So, I'll be SSHing into the remote server and pulling the changes I've made in my local repository.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What OS are you running? I found using a client, such as GitX, really helped me to understand git. Messing around with the command line first off was pretty daunting when I didn't know what the hell I was doing.

Comment: That's a helpful suggestion. I'm using OSX, but the remote is a typical Unix/Linux shared host. I'm definitely hesitant to 'mess around' or muddle through. Normally, I like learning by doing, but in this case, I just need it to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . I've cloned a Git repository to a local

Assuming you have cloned from your remote repo

> Now, I've been asked to pull my changes into the remote repository

well you already did that with

```
git push
```

If you want  to pull little safely from your remote host do first

```
git fetch
```

and later

```
git merge origin/master
```

Lastly to check commits you can do

```
git log
```

Comment: This makes sense and helps clarify the process conceptually. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

A team of mine when learning git memorized these 4 steps:

1. ADD ~ `git add .`
2. COMMIT ~ `git commit -m 'your message'`
3. PULL ~ `git pull` Merge Conflict? Fix it so the code runs the same way.
4. PUSH ~ `git push`

This way, as long as everyone pulls before they push, technically code that doesn't work should never make it live.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It's usually better to rebase than to merge if pulling from a shared central repo. If you pull, you end up with lots of "Merge by Fishz" messages and lose the individual commits. Rebase avoids that, so you get a linear commit history.

Answer (score 0):

If safety is your priority, then *backup* your work and *copy* the repository you're going to work on, to a new place, and work on that until you're sure you *know what you're doing*.

#### RTFM

check out [`git help pull`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-pull) (until [this](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) gets back up)